# как совместить изменения на гитлабе с локальным проектом или удалить изменения на гитлабе?

Tags: git

в общем создал файл прям в https://gitlab.com/ после того как залил туда все изменения.

потом изменил на локалке и не пускает залить и pull не хочет

```
подсказка: Обновления были отклонены, так как верхушка вашей текущей ветки
подсказка: позади ее внешней части. Заберите и слейте внешние изменения 
подсказка: (например, с помощью «git pull …») перед повторной попыткой отправки
подсказка: изменений.
подсказка: Для дополнительной информации, смотрите «Note about fast-forwards»
подсказка: в «git push --help».
```

Comment: "pull не хочет" -- что значит "не хочет"?

Comment: сработало так git pull origin master а не git pull  master

Comment: Ну с удалённого репозитория так и забираются данные)) Вопрос закрыт?))